# Groovy findAll in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, groovy

I have the following array of arrays in groovy

```
def userList = [[name: user1, id:0, ip: 127.0.0.1], [name: user2, id:1, ip: 127.0.0.2], [name: user3, id:2, ip: 127.0.0.3]]
```

I am iterating over another list `rows` and I want to extract the entries from the above list based on index.

```
   rows.eachWithIndex { row, index ->
      groovy.lang.Closure idMatch = { it.id == index }
      def match = userList.findAll(idMatch)
      println(match)
   }
```

match is always returning empty.

The index value shows up correctly as 0,1,2 etc when I print it.

Comment: Your code works for me...

Comment: My guess is that `id` in your `userList` is not an `Integer`

Comment: @tim_yates do I have to use `it.id.toInteger()` ?

Comment: It depends what `id` is...

Comment: Thanks, it worked. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

With Groovy 2.4 and above, one approach would be to use [`indices`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#getIndices(java.util.Collection)) and `collect()` on `rows` instead of `eachWithIndex`:

```
def userList = [
    [name: 'user1', id:0, ip: '127.0.0.1'], 
    [name: 'user2', id:1, ip: '127.0.0.2'], 
    [name: 'user3', id:2, ip: '127.0.0.3']
]

def rows = ['foo', 'bar']

// Using indices
rows.indices.collect { index -> 
    userList.find { it.id == index } 
}

// Using indexed()    
rows.indexed().collect { index, item -> 
    userList.find { it.id == index } 
}
```

Comment: indexed() method or indices is not available it seems. `rows` is a list and I am using grails 2.4.4

Comment: Makes sense, Grails 2.4.4 comes with Groovy 2.3.7.

Comment: With what you have in question, it should print expected results. match does print results. @user2133404

Comment: Thanks, I had to cast the id to integer.